# orbeon-form : eclipse project

Tags: orbeon

Just trying to  use Orbeon API loaded in eclipse :

After a reconfigure of the build path and defining all the jars dependencies that weren't updated, I 'm finally stuck with this scala classes that are not correctly loaded ?

Any help please ?

```
[scalac] /Developer/wksp_juno/orbeon-forms/src/main/java/org/orbeon/oxf/xforms/XFormsContainingDocument.java:62: error: not found: type XBLContainer
   [scalac] public class XFormsContainingDocument extends XBLContainer implements XFormsDocumentLifecycle, Cacheable, XFormsObject {
   [scalac]                                               ^
   [scalac] /Developer/wksp_juno/orbeon-forms/src/main/java/org/orbeon/oxf/resources/ResourceNotFoundException.java:21: error: not found: type OXFException
   [scalac] public class ResourceNotFoundException extends OXFException {
   [scalac]                                                ^
   [scalac] /Developer/wksp_juno/orbeon-forms/src/main/scala/org/orbeon/oxf/common/PEVersion.scala:57: error: fruitless type test: a value of type Throwable cannot also be a org.orbeon.oxf.resources.ResourceNotFoundException
   [scalac]                         case e: ResourceNotFoundException ?
   [scalac]                                 ^
   [scalac] /Developer/wksp_juno/orbeon-forms/src/main/java/org/orbeon/oxf/pipeline/api/ExternalContext.java:164: error: not found: type WebAppContext
   [scalac]     WebAppContext getWebAppContext();
   [scalac]     ^
   [scalac] /Developer/wksp_juno/orbeon-forms/src/main/java/org/orbeon/oxf/processor/ProcessorImpl.java:108: error: not found: type PropertySet
   [scalac]     protected PropertySet getPropertySet() {
   [scalac]               ^
   [scalac] /Developer/wksp_juno/orbeon-forms/src/main/scala/org/orbeon/oxf/controller/PageFlowControllerProcessor.scala:224: error: type mismatch;
   [scalac]  found   : Any
   [scalac]  required: String
   [scalac]                     Seq(PageOrServiceElement(None, submissionPath, Pattern.compile(submissionPath), None, submissionModel, None, configRoot, SubmissionPublicMethods, isPage = true))
   [scalac]                                                    ^
   [scalac] /Developer/wksp_juno/orbeon-forms/src/main/scala/org/orbeon/oxf/controller/PageFlowControllerProcessor.scala:275: error: could not find implicit value for parameter propertySet: org.orbeon.oxf.properties.PropertySet
   [scalac]                 case page: PageOrServiceElement ? PageOrServiceRoute(page, compile)
   [scalac]                                                                     ^
   [scalac] /Developer/wksp_juno/orbeon-forms/src/main/scala/org/orbeon/oxf/controller/PageFlowControllerProcessor.scala:91: error: fruitless type test: a value of type Throwable cannot also be a org.orbeon.oxf.resources.ResourceNotFoundException
   [scalac]                 case e: ResourceNotFoundException ? e.resource
   [scalac]                         ^
   [scalac] /Developer/wksp_juno/orbeon-forms/src/main/scala/org/orbeon/oxf/controller/PageFlowControllerProcessor.scala:171: error: fruitless type test: a value of type Throwable cannot also be a org.orbeon.oxf.resources.ResourceNotFoundException
   [scalac]                         case e: ResourceNotFoundException                        ? if (route.isPage) runNotFoundRoute(Some(t)) else sendNotFound(Some(t))
   [scalac]                                 ^
   [scalac] /Developer/wksp_juno/orbeon-forms/src/main/scala/org/orbeon/oxf/xforms/action/XFormsAPI.scala:219: error: value models is not a member of org.orbeon.oxf.xforms.XFormsContainingDocument
   [scalac]         containingDocument.models find (_.getId == modelId)
   [scalac]                            ^
   [scalac] /Developer/wksp_juno/orbeon-forms/src/main/java/org/orbeon/oxf/xforms/XFormsContainingDocument.java:591: error: not found: type RequestStats
   [scalac]     public RequestStats getRequestStats() {
   [scalac]            ^
   [scalac] /Developer/wksp_juno/orbeon-forms/src/main/scala/org/orbeon/oxf/xforms/model/DataModel.scala:181: error: value getInstanceForNode is not a member of org.orbeon.oxf.xforms.XFormsContainingDocument
   [scalac]         Option(containingDocument.getInstanceForNode(nodeInfo)) map (_.getEffectiveId)
   [scalac]                                   ^
   [scalac] /Developer/wksp_juno/orbeon-forms/src/main/scala/org/orbeon/oxf/xforms/model/DataModel.scala:190: error: value getInstanceForNode is not a member of org.orbeon.oxf.xforms.XFormsContainingDocument
   [scalac]         Option(containingDocument.getInstanceForNode(nodeInfo)) match {
   [scalac]                                   ^
   [scalac] /Developer/wksp_juno/orbeon-forms/src/main/scala/org/orbeon/oxf/xforms/model/DataModel.scala:193: error: value markModified is not a member of Any
   [scalac]                 modifiedInstance.markModified()
   [scalac]                                  ^
   [scalac] /Developer/wksp_juno/orbeon-forms/src/main/scala/org/orbeon/oxf/xforms/model/DataModel.scala:194: error: value model is not a member of Any
   [scalac]                 modifiedInstance.model.markValueChange(nodeInfo, isCalculate)
   [scalac]                                  ^
   [scalac] /Developer/wksp_juno/orbeon-forms/src/main/scala/org/orbeon/oxf/xforms/model/DataModel.scala:197: error: type mismatch;
   [scalac]  found   : Any
   [scalac]  required: org.orbeon.oxf.xforms.event.XFormsEventTarget
   [scalac]                 Dispatch.dispatchEvent(new XXFormsValueChangedEvent(modifiedInstance, nodeInfo, oldValue, newValue))
   [scalac]                                                                     ^
   [scalac] /Developer/wksp_juno/orbeon-forms/src/main/java/org/orbeon/oxf/xforms/XFormsModel.java:58: error: not found: type XFormsEventObserver
   [scalac] public class XFormsModel extends XFormsModelBase implements XFormsEventObserver, XFormsObjectResolver {
   [scalac]                                                             ^
   [scalac] /Developer/wksp_juno/orbeon-forms/src/main/java/org/orbeon/oxf/xforms/XFormsModel.java:210: error: not found: type Model
   [scalac]     public Model getStaticModel() {
   [scalac]            ^
   [scalac] /Developer/wksp_juno/orbeon-forms/src/main/scala/org/orbeon/oxf/fb/ControlOps.scala:581: error: constructor cannot be instantiated to expected type;
   [scalac]  found   : (T1, T2)
   [scalac]  required: Nothing
   [scalac]             controlId ? findControlIdByName(getFormDoc, controlName)
   [scalac]             ^
   [scalac] /Developer/wksp_juno/orbeon-forms/src/main/java/org/orbeon/oxf/xforms/XFormsModel.java:206: error: not found: type XBLContainer
   [scalac]     public XBLContainer container() {
   [scalac]            ^
   [scalac] /Developer/wksp_juno/orbeon-forms/src/main/java/org/orbeon/oxf/xforms/ControlTree.java:258: error: not found: type XFormsContainerControl
   [scalac]     public XFormsContainerControl getRoot() {
   [scalac]            ^
   [scalac] /Developer/wksp_juno/orbeon-forms/src/main/scala/org/orbeon/oxf/pipeline/InitUtils.scala:92: error: fruitless type test: a value of type Throwable cannot also be a org.orbeon.oxf.resources.ResourceNotFoundException
   [scalac]                     case e: ResourceNotFoundException ?
   [scalac]                             ^
   [scalac] /Developer/wksp_juno/orbeon-forms/src/main/java/org/orbeon/oxf/portlet/Portlet2ExternalContext.java:73: error: not found: type WebAppContext
   [scalac]     Portlet2ExternalContext(PipelineContext pipelineContext, WebAppContext webAppContext, PortletRequest portletRequest, boolean amendRequest) {
   [scalac]                                                              ^
   [scalac] /Developer/wksp_juno/orbeon-forms/src/main/scala/org/orbeon/oxf/processor/EmailProcessor.scala:74: error: could not find implicit value for parameter propertySet: org.orbeon.oxf.properties.PropertySet
   [scalac]             valueFromElementOrProperty(messageElement, SMTPHost) getOrElse
   [scalac]                                       ^
   [scalac] /Developer/wksp_juno/orbeon-forms/src/main/scala/org/orbeon/oxf/processor/EmailProcessor.scala:104: error: could not find implicit value for parameter propertySet: org.orbeon.oxf.properties.PropertySet
   [scalac]                 valueFromElementOrProperty(messageElement, Encryption) match {
   [scalac]                                           ^
   [scalac] /Developer/wksp_juno/orbeon-forms/src/main/scala/org/orbeon/oxf/processor/EmailProcessor.scala:134: error: could not find implicit value for parameter propertySet: org.orbeon.oxf.properties.PropertySet
   [scalac]             valueFromElementOrProperty(messageElement, SMTPPort) orElse defaultPort foreach updatePort
   [scalac]                                       ^
   [scalac] /Developer/wksp_juno/orbeon-forms/src/main/java/org/orbeon/oxf/servlet/ServletExternalContext.java:697: error: not found: type WebAppContext
   [scalac]     public ServletExternalContext(PipelineContext pipelineContext, WebAppContext webAppContext, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
   [scalac]                                                                    ^
   [scalac] /Developer/wksp_juno/orbeon-forms/src/main/scala/org/orbeon/oxf/xforms/xbl/XBLContainer.scala:76: error: fruitless type test: a value of type org.orbeon.oxf.xforms.xbl.XBLContainer cannot also be a org.orbeon.oxf.xforms.XFormsContainingDocument
   [scalac]     val containingDocument = ancestorsIterator collectFirst { case cd: XFormsContainingDocument ? cd } get
   [scalac]                                                                        ^
   [scalac] /Developer/wksp_juno/orbeon-forms/src/main/scala/org/orbeon/oxf/xforms/BindingContext.scala:166: error: value getInstanceForNode is not a member of org.orbeon.oxf.xforms.XFormsContainingDocument
   [scalac]             { case node: NodeInfo ? model.containingDocument.getInstanceForNode(node) } orNull
   [scalac]                                                              ^
   [scalac] /Developer/wksp_juno/orbeon-forms/src/main/scala/org/orbeon/oxf/xforms/XFormsInstance.scala:155: error: type mismatch;
   [scalac]  found   : org.orbeon.oxf.xforms.XFormsModel
   [scalac]  required: org.orbeon.oxf.xforms.event.XFormsEventObserver
   [scalac]     def parentEventObserver: XFormsEventObserver = model
   [scalac]                                                    ^
   [scalac] /Developer/wksp_juno/orbeon-forms/src/main/java/org/orbeon/oxf/xforms/ControlTree.java:280: error: not found: type XFormsControl
   [scalac]     public Map<String, XFormsControl> getRepeatControls() {
   [scalac]                        ^
   [scalac] /Developer/wksp_juno/orbeon-forms/src/main/scala/org/orbeon/oxf/xforms/XFormsInstance.scala:223: error: value getEffectiveId is not a member of type parameter B
   [scalac]                 newRepeatControl ? Option(controls.getObjectByEffectiveId(repeatControl.getEffectiveId).asInstanceOf[XFormsRepeatControl])
   [scalac]                                                                                         ^
   [scalac] /Developer/wksp_juno/orbeon-forms/src/main/java/org/orbeon/oxf/xforms/XFormsModel.java:65: error: not found: type Model
   [scalac]     public final Model staticModel;
   [scalac]                  ^
   [scalac] /Developer/wksp_juno/orbeon-forms/src/main/java/org/orbeon/oxf/xforms/analysis/XFormsExtractorContentHandler.java:138: error: not found: type AnnotatedTemplate
   [scalac]             AnnotatedTemplate templateUnderConstruction,
   [scalac]             ^
   [scalac] /Developer/wksp_juno/orbeon-forms/src/main/scala/org/orbeon/oxf/xforms/action/actions/XFormsSetindexAction.scala:62: error: value synchronizeAndRefresh is not a member of org.orbeon.oxf.xforms.XFormsContainingDocument
   [scalac]             interpreter.containingDocument.synchronizeAndRefresh()
   [scalac]                                            ^
   [scalac] /Developer/wksp_juno/orbeon-forms/src/main/java/org/orbeon/oxf/xforms/action/XFormsActionInterpreter.java:405: error: not found: type XFormsObject
   [scalac]     public XFormsObject resolveObject(Element actionElement, String targetStaticOrAbsoluteId) {
   [scalac]            ^
   [scalac] /Developer/wksp_juno/orbeon-forms/src/main/java/org/orbeon/oxf/xforms/XFormsControls.java:430: error: not found: type XFormsControl
   [scalac]     public XFormsControl getFocusedControl() {
   [scalac]            ^
   [scalac] /Developer/wksp_juno/orbeon-forms/src/main/java/org/orbeon/oxf/xforms/XFormsControls.java:434: error: not found: type XFormsControl
   [scalac]     public void setFocusedControl(XFormsControl focusedControl) {
   [scalac]                                   ^
   [scalac] /Developer/wksp_juno/orbeon-forms/src/main/java/org/orbeon/oxf/xforms/ControlTree.java:270: error: not found: type XFormsControl
   [scalac]     public XFormsControl getControl(String effectiveId) {
   [scalac]            ^
   [scalac] /Developer/wksp_juno/orbeon-forms/src/main/scala/org/orbeon/oxf/xforms/control/Focus.scala:120: error: value isFocusable is not a member of Any
   [scalac]                     case Some(newReference) if ! newReference.isFocusable ?
   [scalac]                                                               ^
   [scalac] /Developer/wksp_juno/orbeon-forms/src/main/scala/org/orbeon/oxf/xforms/control/Focus.scala:124: error: value ne is not a member of Any
   [scalac]                     case Some(newReference) if newReference ne focusedBefore ?
   [scalac]                                                             ^
   [scalac] /Developer/wksp_juno/orbeon-forms/src/main/scala/org/orbeon/oxf/xforms/control/Focus.scala:129: error: type mismatch;
   [scalac]  found   : Any
   [scalac]  required: org.orbeon.oxf.xforms.control.XFormsControl
   [scalac]                         onFocus(newReference)
   [scalac]                                 ^
   [scalac] /Developer/wksp_juno/orbeon-forms/src/main/scala/org/orbeon/oxf/xforms/action/XFormsAPI.scala:99: error: value >= is not a member of Nothing
   [scalac]                 { case newIndex if newIndex >= 0 ? newIndex }
   [scalac]                                             ^
   [scalac] /Developer/wksp_juno/orbeon-forms/src/main/java/org/orbeon/oxf/xforms/action/XFormsActionInterpreter.java:80: error: not found: type XBLContainer
   [scalac]     public XBLContainer container() {
   [scalac]            ^
   [scalac] /Developer/wksp_juno/orbeon-forms/src/main/java/org/orbeon/oxf/xforms/submission/XFormsModelSubmission.java:65: error: not found: type XFormsEventTarget
   [scalac] public class XFormsModelSubmission extends XFormsModelSubmissionBase implements XFormsEventTarget, XFormsEventObserver {
   [scalac]                                                                                 ^
   [scalac] /Developer/wksp_juno/orbeon-forms/src/main/java/org/orbeon/oxf/xforms/submission/XFormsModelSubmission.java:65: error: not found: type XFormsEventObserver
   [scalac] public class XFormsModelSubmission extends XFormsModelSubmissionBase implements XFormsEventTarget, XFormsEventObserver {
   [scalac]                                                                                                    ^
   [scalac] /Developer/wksp_juno/orbeon-forms/src/main/scala/org/orbeon/oxf/xforms/action/XFormsAPI.scala:269: error: type mismatch;
   [scalac]  found   : org.orbeon.oxf.xforms.submission.XFormsModelSubmission
   [scalac]  required: org.orbeon.oxf.xforms.event.XFormsEventTarget
   [scalac]         try Dispatch.dispatchEvent(new XFormsSubmitEvent(submission, properties))
   [scalac]                                                          ^
   [scalac] /Developer/wksp_juno/orbeon-forms/src/main/java/org/orbeon/oxf/xforms/control/controls/XFormsCaseControl.java:23: error: not found: type XFormsNoSingleNodeContainerControl
   [scalac] public class XFormsCaseControl extends XFormsNoSingleNodeContainerControl {
   [scalac]                                        ^
   [scalac] /Developer/wksp_juno/orbeon-forms/src/main/java/org/orbeon/oxf/xforms/control/controls/XXFormsDialogControl.java:31: error: not found: type XFormsNoSingleNodeContainerControl
   [scalac] public class XXFormsDialogControl extends XFormsNoSingleNodeContainerControl {
   [scalac]                                           ^
   [scalac] /Developer/wksp_juno/orbeon-forms/src/main/scala/org/orbeon/oxf/xforms/action/actions/XXFormsShowAction.scala:51: error: type mismatch;
   [scalac]  found   : org.orbeon.oxf.xforms.control.controls.XXFormsDialogControl
   [scalac]  required: org.orbeon.oxf.xforms.event.XFormsEventTarget
   [scalac]         val newEvent = new XXFormsDialogOpenEvent(properties, targetDialog, neighborEffectiveId.orNull, constrainToViewport)
   [scalac]                                                               ^
   [scalac] /Developer/wksp_juno/orbeon-forms/src/main/scala/org/orbeon/oxf/xforms/action/XFormsAction.scala:96: error: value synchronizeAndRefresh is not a member of org.orbeon.oxf.xforms.XFormsContainingDocument
   [scalac]             context.containingDocument.synchronizeAndRefresh()
   [scalac]                                        ^
   [scalac] /Developer/wksp_juno/orbeon-forms/src/main/java/org/orbeon/oxf/xforms/action/XFormsActionInterpreter.java:445: error: not found: type Scope
   [scalac]     public Scope getActionScope(Element actionElement) {
   [scalac]            ^
   [scalac] /Developer/wksp_juno/orbeon-forms/src/main/java/org/orbeon/oxf/xforms/XFormsContextStack.java:267: error: not found: type Scope
   [scalac]                             Element bindingElement, NamespaceMapping bindingElementNamespaceMapping, String sourceEffectiveId, Scope scope, boolean handleNonFatal) {
   [scalac]                                                                                                                                ^
   [scalac] /Developer/wksp_juno/orbeon-forms/src/main/java/org/orbeon/oxf/xforms/XFormsContextStack.java:244: error: not found: type Scope
   [scalac]     public void pushBinding(Element bindingElement, String sourceEffectiveId, Scope scope, boolean handleNonFatal) {
   [scalac]                                                                               ^
   [scalac] /Developer/wksp_juno/orbeon-forms/src/main/java/org/orbeon/oxf/xforms/XFormsContextStack.java:240: error: not found: type Scope
   [scalac]     public void pushBinding(Element bindingElement, String sourceEffectiveId, Scope scope) {
   [scalac]                                                                               ^
   [scalac] /Developer/wksp_juno/orbeon-forms/src/main/java/org/orbeon/oxf/xforms/XFormsContextStack.java:122: error: not found: value XFormsFunction
   [scalac]     public XFormsFunction.Context getFunctionContext(String sourceEffectiveId) {
   [scalac]            ^
   [scalac] /Developer/wksp_juno/orbeon-forms/src/main/java/org/orbeon/oxf/xforms/action/actions/XFormsLoadAction.java:30: error: not found: type XFormsAction
   [scalac] public class XFormsLoadAction extends XFormsAction {
   [scalac]                                       ^
   [scalac] /Developer/wksp_juno/orbeon-forms/src/main/java/org/orbeon/oxf/xforms/action/actions/XFormsResetAction.java:26: error: not found: type XFormsAction
   [scalac] public class XFormsResetAction extends XFormsAction {
   [scalac]                                        ^
   [scalac] /Developer/wksp_juno/orbeon-forms/src/main/java/org/orbeon/oxf/xforms/action/actions/XFormsMessageAction.java:32: error: not found: type XFormsAction
   [scalac] public class XFormsMessageAction extends XFormsAction {
   [scalac]                                          ^
   [scalac] /Developer/wksp_juno/orbeon-forms/src/main/java/org/orbeon/oxf/xforms/action/actions/XFormsInsertAction.java:42: error: not found: type XFormsAction
   [scalac] public class XFormsInsertAction extends XFormsAction {
   [scalac]                                         ^
   [scalac] /Developer/wksp_juno/orbeon-forms/src/main/java/org/orbeon/oxf/xforms/action/actions/XFormsDeleteAction.java:36: error: not found: type XFormsAction
   [scalac] public class XFormsDeleteAction extends XFormsAction {
   [scalac]                                         ^
   [scalac] /Developer/wksp_juno/orbeon-forms/src/main/java/org/orbeon/oxf/xforms/action/actions/XXFormsHideAction.java:25: error: not found: type XFormsAction
   [scalac] public class XXFormsHideAction extends XFormsAction {
   [scalac]                                        ^
   [scalac] /Developer/wksp_juno/orbeon-forms/src/main/java/org/orbeon/oxf/xforms/action/actions/XXFormsInvalidateInstanceAction.java:27: error: not found: type XFormsAction
   [scalac] public class XXFormsInvalidateInstanceAction extends XFormsAction {
   [scalac]                                                      ^
   [scalac] /Developer/wksp_juno/orbeon-forms/src/main/java/org/orbeon/oxf/xforms/action/actions/XXFormsInvalidateInstancesAction.java:25: error: not found: type XFormsAction
   [scalac] public class XXFormsInvalidateInstancesAction extends XFormsAction {
   [scalac]                                                       ^
   [scalac] /Developer/wksp_juno/orbeon-forms/src/main/java/org/orbeon/oxf/xforms/action/actions/XXFormsJoinSubmissions.java:21: error: not found: type XFormsAction
   [scalac] public class XXFormsJoinSubmissions extends XFormsAction {
   [scalac]                                             ^
   [scalac] /Developer/wksp_juno/orbeon-forms/src/main/scala/org/orbeon/oxf/xforms/action/actions/RRRActions.scala:30: error: type mismatch;
   [scalac]  found   : org.orbeon.oxf.xforms.XFormsModel
   [scalac]  required: org.orbeon.oxf.xforms.event.XFormsEventTarget
   [scalac]     def createEvent(model: XFormsModel, applyDefaults: Boolean) = new XFormsRebuildEvent(model)
   [scalac]                                                                                          ^
   [scalac] /Developer/wksp_juno/orbeon-forms/src/main/scala/org/orbeon/oxf/xforms/action/actions/RRRActions.scala:39: error: overloaded method constructor XFormsRecalculateEvent with alternatives:
   [scalac]   (target: org.orbeon.oxf.xforms.event.XFormsEventTarget,applyDefaults: Boolean)org.orbeon.oxf.xforms.event.events.XFormsRecalculateEvent <and>
   [scalac]   (target: org.orbeon.oxf.xforms.event.XFormsEventTarget,properties: org.orbeon.oxf.xforms.event.XFormsEvent.PropertyGetter)org.orbeon.oxf.xforms.event.events.XFormsRecalculateEvent
   [scalac]  cannot be applied to (org.orbeon.oxf.xforms.XFormsModel, Boolean)
   [scalac]     def createEvent(model: XFormsModel, applyDefaults: Boolean) = new XFormsRecalculateEvent(model, applyDefaults)
   [scalac]                                                                   ^
   [scalac] /Developer/wksp_juno/orbeon-forms/src/main/scala/org/orbeon/oxf/xforms/action/actions/RRRActions.scala:44: error: type mismatch;
   [scalac]  found   : org.orbeon.oxf.xforms.XFormsModel
   [scalac]  required: org.orbeon.oxf.xforms.event.XFormsEventTarget
   [scalac]     def createEvent(model: XFormsModel, applyDefaults: Boolean) = new XFormsRevalidateEvent(model)
   [scalac]                                                                                             ^
   [scalac] /Developer/wksp_juno/orbeon-forms/src/main/java/org/orbeon/oxf/xforms/XFormsContextStack.java:71: error: not found: type XBLContainer
   [scalac]     public final XBLContainer container;
   [scalac]                  ^
   [scalac] /Developer/wksp_juno/orbeon-forms/src/main/java/org/orbeon/oxf/xforms/XFormsContextStack.java:201: error: not found: type VariableAnalysisTrait
   [scalac]     public BindingContext.VariableInfo scopeVariable(VariableAnalysisTrait staticVariable, String sourceEffectiveId, boolean handleNonFatal) {
   [scalac]                                                      ^
   [scalac] /Developer/wksp_juno/orbeon-forms/src/main/java/org/orbeon/oxf/xforms/action/XFormsActionInterpreter.java:105: error: not found: type ElementAnalysis
   [scalac]     public void runAction(ElementAnalysis actionAnalysis) {
   [scalac]                           ^
   [scalac] /Developer/wksp_juno/orbeon-forms/src/main/scala/org/orbeon/oxf/xforms/action/actions/XFormsActionAction.scala:64: error: value execute is not a member of Object
   [scalac]             XFormsActions.getScriptAction.execute(actionContext)
   [scalac]                                           ^
   [scalac] /Developer/wksp_juno/orbeon-forms/src/main/scala/org/orbeon/oxf/xforms/action/actions/XFormsRefreshAction.scala:45: error: type mismatch;
   [scalac]  found   : org.orbeon.oxf.xforms.XFormsModel
   [scalac]  required: org.orbeon.oxf.xforms.event.XFormsEventTarget
   [scalac]         Dispatch.dispatchEvent(new XFormsRefreshEvent(model))
   [scalac]                                                       ^
   [scalac] /Developer/wksp_juno/orbeon-forms/src/main/scala/org/orbeon/oxf/xforms/action/actions/XFormsToggleAction.scala:31: error: fruitless type test: a value of type org.orbeon.oxf.xforms.control.XFormsControl cannot also be a org.orbeon.oxf.xforms.control.controls.XFormsCaseControl
   [scalac]             case Some(caseControl: XFormsCaseControl) ?
   [scalac]                                    ^
   [scalac] /Developer/wksp_juno/orbeon-forms/src/main/scala/org/orbeon/oxf/xforms/action/actions/XFormsToggleAction.scala:49: error: value synchronizeAndRefresh is not a member of org.orbeon.oxf.xforms.XFormsContainingDocument
   [scalac]             XFormsAPI.containingDocument.synchronizeAndRefresh()
   [scalac]                                          ^
   [scalac] /Developer/wksp_juno/orbeon-forms/src/main/scala/org/orbeon/oxf/xforms/action/actions/XFormsToggleAction.scala:51: error: value parent is not a member of org.orbeon.oxf.xforms.control.controls.XFormsCaseControl
   [scalac]         if (caseControl.parent.isRelevant && ! caseControl.isSelected) {
   [scalac]                         ^
   [scalac] /Developer/wksp_juno/orbeon-forms/src/main/java/org/orbeon/oxf/xforms/XFormsContainingDocument.java:1054: error: not found: type ScriptInterpreter
   [scalac]     public ScriptInterpreter getScriptInterpreter() {
   [scalac]            ^
   [scalac] /Developer/wksp_juno/orbeon-forms/src/main/java/org/orbeon/oxf/xforms/XFormsContainingDocument.java:787: error: not found: type XFormsEvent
   [scalac]     public void addScriptToRun(org.orbeon.oxf.xforms.Script script, XFormsEvent event, XFormsEventObserver eventObserver) {
   [scalac]                                                                     ^
   [scalac] /Developer/wksp_juno/orbeon-forms/src/main/java/org/orbeon/oxf/xforms/XFormsContainingDocument.java:787: error: not found: type XFormsEventObserver
   [scalac]     public void addScriptToRun(org.orbeon.oxf.xforms.Script script, XFormsEvent event, XFormsEventObserver eventObserver) {
   [scalac]                                                                                        ^
   [scalac] /Developer/wksp_juno/orbeon-forms/src/main/java/org/orbeon/oxf/xforms/action/XFormsActionInterpreter.java:55: error: not found: type XFormsEvent
   [scalac]     public final XFormsEvent event;
   [scalac]                  ^
   [scalac] /Developer/wksp_juno/orbeon-forms/src/main/java/org/orbeon/oxf/xforms/action/XFormsActionInterpreter.java:56: error: not found: type XFormsEventObserver
   [scalac]     public final XFormsEventObserver eventObserver;
   [scalac]                  ^
   [scalac] /Developer/wksp_juno/orbeon-forms/src/main/scala/org/orbeon/oxf/xforms/action/actions/XXFormsShowAction.scala:32: error: fruitless type test: a value of type org.orbeon.oxf.xforms.control.XFormsControl cannot also be a org.orbeon.oxf.xforms.control.controls.XXFormsDialogControl
```

....
....
       [scalac]                                            ^
       [scalac] 231 errors found

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your Eclipse might not be setup to compile the Scala code. Maybe the simplest way to get there is to use [Scala IDE](http://scala-ide.org/). The Scala IDE folks created a [video about the installation of Scala IDE](http://scala-ide.org/download/current.html), which you You might find useful.

Comment: It's also happening out from the IDE (Eclipse). A simple build with ant gives the same result...

Comment: Nope. Would it be something related to scala source path ?

Comment: It should be build out of the box. Can you try again, in a clean directory, without starting Eclipse, doing a `git clone git://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms.git` then `ant orbeon-war`?

Comment: Sorry it didn't work, i was at a meeting seeing the build so quickly i thought it worked ... The same errors happened after a new clone followed by an ant build (versions 1.8.2 and 1.9 of ant tested on mac OSX).

Comment: This is really strange. I am also using OS X, and just tried doing a `git clone git://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms.git ; ant orbeon-war` and it is working with no problem. I happen to have Ant 1.8.2 here. Also, this compiles fine on Travis-CI and another server on which we do automated builds. I used to have Java 1.6, and now updated to 1.7, and everything still works fine. So I am really not sure why it wouldn't work on your machine. Do you have a clue?

Comment: UP and running! After a clean up of the ant folder in my maven home repository (~/.m2 on OSX). Maven dependencies relationships are sometimes a voodoo stuff. Thanks for your help anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Today, I am able to setup Orbeon Project inside eclipse, and I am able to run it against the server and allow me to debug the code.

I have created wiki in order to help other Developers to setup the same thing, and try to understand the project by debugging.

Please refer follow steps in order to setup the project:

1. Download eclipse Scala-IDE from the link: http://scala-ide.org/
2. Unzip the archive and save it in your file system.
3. Open eclipse -> File Menu -> Click On Import -> Select Projects From Git -> Next.
4. Entet URI as git@github.com:orbeon/orbeon-forms.git, and select CE 4.5 Branch, and Select next.
5. Select New Project Wizard, and Click on Finish.
6. Now Project Selection Wizard, Select New Scala Project. Name as Orbeon-Forms.
7. If you do not see code inside project then Right Click on Project -> Import -> Existing Project From File System -> Select the location where you clone the Orbeon Project. -> Click On Finish.
8. Now, Create resource-local folder inside the project, and copy the content of resource-packaged folder into resource-local.
9. Now create recursive folder as this path inside project: /build/orbeon-war/WEB-INF/classes.
10. Now, Right click on project -> Select Properties -> Select Build Path.

11.Now, setup your Default output folder to *Orbeon-Forms/build/orbeon-war/WEB-INF/classes*.

1. Remove all source folder, and add src/main/java, src/main/scala, src/main/resource, src/main/resource-packaged, src/main/resource-local.
2. Now Go to the, Libraries tab, and remove all jars. (**Note:** Do not remove JRE and Scala Library.)
3. Now add all jars from lib folder. and Click Apply.
4. Now Click on Resource, Text File Encoding. Click on other, and change it to "UTF-8".
5. Now Close the properties windows.
6. Now you may get, cross-compiled error for some jars for mongodb and GridFS. Remove those jars from your Build Path.
7. Now, you will get error in few files in Problem Window.
8. Right now, I have removed MongoDBPersistence.scala file. and for other file, I comment the code.
9. Now open, LoggerFactory.scala file, and comment following line:
   _String log4jConfigURL = Properties.instance().getPropertySet().getStringOrURIAsString(LOG4J_DOM_CONFIG_PROPERTY, false);_

And copy paste the following line after that commented line:
*String log4jConfigURL = "oxf:/default-log4j.xml";*

**Note:** If you do not do above change, you will get error while starting your server.

1. Now, clean your project, and build it. eClipse should compile all scala and java file, generate class files under

Orbeon-Forms/build/orbeon-war/WEB-INF/classes.

1. Now, Right click on build.xml -> Properties -> Run/Debug Settings -> Click on New -> Select Ant Build.
2. New Window named Edit Configuration will open up.
3. Click on Properties Tab -> Uncheck "Use Global Properties as specified in Ant runtime Preference".
4. Click on Add Property. Give name skip.compilation and value true. Click Ok, and close the Configuration. (**Note:** Now Ant will not Compile Scala and Java Files.)
5. Now, run orbeon-war ant target from eclipse. You should be able to see Build Successfully after build finished.
6. I am using Apache Tomcat as server. Go to server.xml under conf directory of your Tomcat directory.
7. Add following context under  :

**Note:** value for docBase will changed based on the your project location in your file system.

1. Now open command prompt, and go to your /bin.
2. Run, catalina jpda start.
3. It shows server has been started.
4. Open, localhost:8080/orbeon in your browser. You will see Orbeon Home page.
5. Now, Go to eclipse -> Run Menu -> Debug Configuration -> Select Remote Java Application -> click on "+" Sign.
6. Now enter host as localhost and port as 8000. This will allow Remote Debugging.

Comment: I referred following two links:

 http://wiki.orbeon.com/forms/doc/contributor-guide/development-environment/java-development

 http://wiki.orbeon.com/forms/doc/developer-guide/admin/installing