# Fruitless Type Test warning because Scala interprets Java API Exception as a Scala object

Tags: java, scala, exception, warnings

I am using a Java API in a Scala project and the API has methods that throw an exception named **BIARException**.
However, in the code where I try to catch that exception, the Scala compiler issues a warning:

> Fruitless type test: A value of type Throwable cannot also be a
>   com.businessobjects.sdk.biar.BIARException

The code is like this:

```
import com.businessobjects.sdk.biar.BIARException

object Example 
{
  val i = try 
  {
    42
  }
  catch 
  {
    case e : BIARException => 43 // Warning: Fruitless type test ...
    case e @ BIARException => 44
  }
}
```

It looks like Scala considers BIARException as an object and not a type.

How can that be? and how do I best avoid it?

The BIARException is indeed a type that inherits from Throwable. Here is a clip from the documentation:

```
java.lang.Object
  extended by java.lang.Throwable
    extended by java.lang.Exception
      extended by com.businessobjects.sdk.biar.BIARException
```

The documentation is available here: https://help.sap.com/javadocs/boe/xi3/boe/en/com/businessobjects/sdk/biar/BIARException.html

I am running Scala version 2.10 in Eclipse 4.2.2

Comment: Is that a warning of the eclipse presentation compiler or actually a warning emitted when compiling the project? Have you tried if the warning appears with Scala 2.11? The line `case e @ BIARException => ...` looks very odd to me. If that compiles it implies that there is such an object, which AFAIK cannot happen with the class you link to. Are you sure, you don't have created accidentally a value named `BIARException` in your code?

Comment: Have you seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16019152/orbeon-form-eclipse-project) — perhaps your build is corrupted. Have you tried to clean the project first?

Comment: Is the BIARException the only Exception that may occur in try block? If it is, you may use scala.util.Try and then pattern match it. Or you may specify it as `e: Exception` and it should work. `@` symbol doesn't make sense here (It makes sense if you're dealing with pattern matching on case classes, list and other stuff, that implements `unapply` method.

Comment: The warning is given by eclipse but also if compiling with SBT in a terminal.

I will try to replicate with Scala 2.11.

The line case e @ BIARException was just included in order to show that there is no error matching against BIARException as an object.

I experimented some more and for some odd reason the warning disappeared when I continued developing and had to include more JARs. Maybe the compiler just got confused.